# How to close BluetoothServerSocket while it waiting for connection?

Tags: android, bluetooth

How to force `BluetoothServerSocket` to stop waiting for an incoming connection started with `accept()`?

When I'm calling `stop()` all I get is *"ERROR/BluetoothSppPort(2211): invalid port state for disconnection"* in LogCat.

I need to stop controlling thread but it can't be destroyed while the socket is waiting for a connection.

I know about `accept(int timeout)` but it is not what I need.

Are there any solutions or workarounds?

Comment: To clarify, a connection comes in, accept() is called, but before accept() finishes, you are looking to unaccept the connection?

Comment: I'm trying to handle case when my app is waiting for incoming connections and user decided to interrupt before some device connected.

There is no problems when some device connects, BluetoothServerSocket gives connection and i can close my AcceptThread and proceed to communication with client device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (socket == null) {
        try {
            socket = mmServerSocket.accept(50);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if( UserReqestToExit )//if the user reqest to exit ,use sync
                return;
        }
        // If a connection was accepted
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```